# SVN Commit Segmentation Fault

Tags: svn

I am trying to commit something to our SVN repo. However, I keep getting this error:

```
svn commit google-dev.xml -m "Updated with CS Tools configuration changes."
Sending        google-dev.xml
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: 'pre-commit' hook failed with error output:
/var/lib/svn/tnc/hooks/pre-commit: line 76: 25743 Segmentation fault /var/lib/svn/scripts/case-insensitive.py ${REPOS} ${TXN}
```

I can not figure out what the cause of this is. Is it in the precommit hook python? Or, with the SVN software having problems with the hook? Or something else?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that the hook script you've configured is faulting.
I suspect that this script either isn't configured properly (missing dependencies?) or really found another file in the repository with the same name but differing in case.

If you're using the official script from the svn repository, get the latest one from the svn trunk instead since an older version of that script had problems with big repositories.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've sent this info to our SA. I'll respond back with what we find. :)

Comment: Actually what happened was that the SA was updating the software and mangled the PATH variable to point to the default SVN install instead of the one that have customized. Again, thanks for your help! :)